# Route user from my site to another link

Tags: php, url, url-routing

I am creating a url dynamicaly like **"www.abc.com/somecode"** against that i have an orignal url saved in db say **"www.google.com"**.

I am using htaacess to call the function where  have a small routing module which checks the org url from db and route user to that on hit of **"www.abc.com/somecode"**. my htaccess rule is something like

```
RewriteRule ^sitename/([^/.]+)/?$ rootclass.php?action=outlinks&linkid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Actually I am saving the info of user who click on my url, for that i am using **ipinfo** like `$ipdetails = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$userip}/json"));`. after saving the user info from **$ipdetails** and getting org link from db i am using header function to route the user to that url like `header('location:'.$orglink);` .Issue is there is some time a click from different states like "US, CA", which is not an authentic click (no user clicked from those regions). On local it is working perfect. I want to stop those clicks .

I am not sure why i am getting those clicks. Can any body help

Comment: I'm sorry, at the moment I don't really understand your question. How can you be sure that you don't have some users from other locations? And how do you get the infos about the users in the first place? It is nearly impossible to get a 100% match between user-client informations and the geolocation of the machine on which the client is running (VPN, dynamic IPs, mobile devices..)

Comment: If you don't show use your code we can't help

Comment: @cypherabe i am sure because currently i m the only 1 who is testing , and i m not in those states . issue is not the authenticity of the info . It is the click generation .

Comment: @DestinatioN i have edited my question . Please check.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you get those mysterious clicks only on an online testsystem? maybe some robots / crawler already tried your site...I would check the access log of the server for "foreign" IPs

Comment: yes i am getting that on online test system . But as i said those link are dynamically created and they are not page links . So can still bots or crawler crawl them ?